# Google Maps V3 API map doesn't center correctly

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

from today I've been experiencing an issue with Google Maps resulting into not centering maps when I add some IndoBoxes into map.

I have a few InfoBoxes as follows:

```
var labels = [ 
   new InfoBox({
        content: "Old Town (Stare Mesto)",
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.088979, 14.414921),
        boxStyle: {
                   border: "2px solid white",
                   textAlign: "center",
                   color: "white",
                   fontSize: "8pt",
                   fontWeight: "bold",
                   width: "200px",
                   height: "17px",
                   background: "black",
                   opacity: 0.5,
                   filter: "alpha(opacity=50)"
        }
   }),
   new InfoBox({
        content: "New Town (Nove mesto)",
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.084243, 14.424405),
        boxStyle: {
                   border: "2px solid white",
                   textAlign: "center",
                   color: "white",
                   fontSize: "8pt",
                   fontWeight: "bold",
                   width: "200px",
                   height: "17px",
                   background: "black",
                   opacity: 0.5,
                   filter: "alpha(opacity=50)"
        }
   })
];
```

If I add them on map

```
for (var i in labels) {
    labels[i].open(map);
}
```

Then map viewport is moved to these labels. Even If I call map.setCenter(someLatLngObject) center is stucked on those InfoBoxes.

Is that behavior expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the disableAutoPan option?

```
 new InfoBox({
        disableAutoPan: true,
        content: "New Town (Nove mesto)",
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.084243, 14.424405),
```